# Using tryCatch function of R in a loop

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

I want to use `tryCatch` function in a loop which sometimes works but sometimes it does not, and I do not know where does it have errors to solve the problem and create a loop which always works. So I want it just to neglect the error and go to next round. To simplify the problem, for example, I have this `x`, and I want to have `sqrt` of each value. I write:

```r
x <- c(1, 2, "a", 4)
for (i in x) {
    y <- tryCatch(print(sqrt(i)) , error = function(e) { return(0) } )
    if (y==0) { 
        print("NOT POSSIBLE")
        next
    }
}
```

I suppose this code should give me this answer:

```
[1] 1
[1] 1.414214
[1] "NOT POSSIBLE"
[1] 2
```

but it gives me this:

```
[1] "NOT POSSIBLE"
[1] "NOT POSSIBLE"
[1] "NOT POSSIBLE"
[1] "NOT POSSIBLE"
```

I could not find anywhere explaining that why this happens. Why this function does not apply to each round of the loop separately and what can I do about it?

Comment: If you have at least one character element in a vector, all the elements becomes character.  Instead you may need a `list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is a that one of the elements in the `vector` is `character` and a `vector` cannot have mixed types.  So, it is coerced to `character`.  Instead we should have a `list` where each element can have different `type`s

```
x <- list(1,2,"a" , 4)
```

Now, running the OP' code gives

```
for (i in x) {
   y <- tryCatch(print(sqrt(i)) , error= function(e) {return(0)}  )
   if (y==0) {print("NOT POSSIBLE")
              next}
 }
#[1] 1
#[1] 1.414214
#[1] "NOT POSSIBLE"
#[1] 2
```

---

If we can use only a `vector`, then there should be a provision to convert it to `numeric` within the loop, but it would also return an `NA` for the third element as

```
as.numeric('a')
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

and ends the `for` loop